# Date Formatting Breaks with 2.0.0

Tags: dygraphs

Been using 1.1.1 for a while and decided to try upgrading to 2.0.0.  With 1.1.1, the following snippet works as expected:

```
axes: {
    x: {
        axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisLabelFormatter,
        valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateValueFormatter,
        ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
    }
},
xValueParser: function (x) { return 1000 * x; },
```

Under 2.0.0, the same breaks interactivity—mouseovers stop functioning and the graph legend no longer updates.  What must I change here to support 2.0.0?  JavaScript is not my strong suite.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said before the only thing that was not working in your code was the valueFormatter. 
You got a time with the structure "201609260507.06" and you multiplied it by 100 to remove the dot. Then you had a number with the date in a custom format.

What I have done is to create a custom value formatter which gets the value in that format, parse the number to a string, and get all the information about the date in that string. You can modify the formatDate function (at the bottom of the javascript code) the way you want.

I hope that this will be a real solution for you. Below you have the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lucidio/9jgtse5o/2/

---

UPDATED

In the case you want to use the unix time in milliseconds (i.e: 1491483906), then you can create a new javascript date from the date

```
valueFormatter: function(ms){
    var date = new Date(ms);
    return date;
},
```

And if you need you can use also a formatter function to plot in the date exactly what you want before returning the date

---

```js
var data = "date,totalIn,totalOut,interacOut,tcp_ackOut,regularOut,extwlanOut,torrentOut,extwlanIn\n" +
   "201609260505.06,1926,-1641,-64,-202,-1534,0,0,0\n" +
   "201609260506.06,1060,-1230,-101,-68,-1187,0,0,0\n" +
   "201609260507.06,3127,-2421,-123,-79,-2383,0,0,0\n" +
   "201609260508.06,5624,-2518,-45,-623,-2187,0,0,0\n" +
   "201609260509.06,998,-1190,-100,-45,-1160,0,0,0";
 q = new Dygraph(
   document.getElementById("qdiv"),
   data, {
     // Appears axisLabelColor is no longer supported in 2.0
     // axisLabelColor: 'darkgrey',
     // logscale: true,
     // labelsDiv: 'qldiv',
     title: 'queues',
     titleHeight: 32,
     axes: {
       x: {
         axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisLabelFormatter,
         valueFormatter: function(ms){
            var formattedDate = formatDate(ms);
            return formattedDate;
          },
         ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
       }
     },
     xValueParser: function(x) {
       return 1000 * x;
     },
     // xValueParser: function (x) { return 1000 * parseInt(x); },
     fillGraph: true,
     stackedGraph: true,
     // strokeBorderWidth: 1,
     // strokeWidth: 2,
     // totalIn,totalOut,interacOut,tcp_ackOut,regularOut,extwlanOut,torrentOut,extwlanIn
     visibility: [false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false],
     // colors: ['black', 'black', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'red'],
     colors: ['black', 'black', 'coral', 'dodgerblue', 'forestgreen', 'blueviolet', 'gold'],
     // iWantHue default soft
     // colors: ['black', 'black', '#cb673e', '#648ace', '#5ba962', '#ab62c0', '#a9983d', '#c95779'],
     // iWantHue fancy light hard
     // colors: ['black', 'black', '#c2007a', '#59dacd', '#019a3f', '#793ec4', '#c9b800', '#c00613'],
     // iWantHue fluo soft
     // colors: ['black', 'black', '#cb5c42', '#648ace', '#60a85f', '#a361c7', '#b3953f', '#cb5c42'],
     fillAlpha: .5,
     animatedZooms: true,
     highlightCircleSize: 6,
     highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: .9,
     // Disabled highlightSeriesOpts as it always seemed to highlight the first item in the series and is not very useful in a stacked graph
     // highlightSeriesOpts: {
     // strokeWidth: 4,
     // highlightCircleSize: 6
     // },
     // labelsSeparateLines: true,
     labelsShowZeroValues: false,
     legend: 'always',
     labelsKMG2: true
   });
 b = new Dygraph(
   document.getElementById("bdiv"),
   data, {
     // Appears axisLabelColor is no longer supported in 2.0
     // axisLabelColor: 'darkgrey',
     // While logscale would be great here, it doesn't work with negative values
     // logscale: true,
     title: 'bandwidth',
     titleHeight: 32,
     axes: {
       x: {
         axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisLabelFormatter,
         valueFormatter: function(ms){
            var formattedDate = formatDate(ms);
            return formattedDate;
          },
         ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
       }
     },
     xValueParser: function(x) {
       return 1000 * x;
     },
     fillGraph: true,
     visibility: [true, true, false, false, false, false, false, true],
     // colors: ['green', 'blue'],
     colors: ['forestgreen', 'dodgerblue', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'firebrick'],
     fillAlpha: .5,
     animatedZooms: true,
     highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha: .9,
     highlightSeriesOpts: {
       strokeWidth: 4,
       highlightCircleSize: 6
     },
     labelsShowZeroValues: false,
     // labels: ['in', 'out', 'guest'],
     legend: 'always',
     labelsKMG2: true
   });
    
   function formatDate(d) {
      var stringDate = String(d);
        var yyyy = stringDate.substring(0,4);
        var MM = stringDate.substring(4,6);
        var dd = stringDate.substring(6,8);
        var HH = stringDate.substring(8,10);
        var mm = stringDate.substring(10,12);
        var ss = stringDate.substring(12,14);
        return yyyy + "-" + MM + "-" + dd + " " + HH + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
      }
```

```css
dygraph-label.dygraph-title {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  // font-size: large;
  color: white;
  // color: floralwhite;
}

// .dygraph-label.dygraph-xlabel
// .dygraph-label.dygraph-ylabel
.dygraph-axis-label.dygraph-axis-label-x {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}

.dygraph-axis-label.dygraph-axis-label-y {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}

.dygraph-legend {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small !important;
  color: white;
  // color: floralwhite;
  background: transparent !important;
  // background: rgba(169, 169, 169, 0.4) !important;
  left: auto !important;
  // left: 60px !important;
  // top: auto !important;
  // bottom: 20px !important;
  right: 10px !important;
  // right: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
  // text-align: right !important;
  // overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: auto !important;
}

#root {
  left: 25px;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#qdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

#bdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.js"></script>
<title>egress queues</title>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="qdiv"></div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="bdiv"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: A sincere thank you for taking the time to investigate and resolve this Lucidio.  I just realized the date format I used in my JSFiddles was incorrect and I’m very sorry for misleading you here.  I’m using the UNIX Epoch timestamp format and I got the idea of multiplying by 1000 from http://dygraphs.com/data.html#csv (I updated your JSFiddle to reflect the correct date format at https://jsfiddle.net/9jgtse5o/4/).  Even with the correct date format the problem still exists, but your function resolves it.  Thank you again!

Comment: For what it’s worth, I also originally used some cues from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828513/after-loading-utc-data-dygraph-axis-dates-are-too-long-and-wont-adjust and, obviously, this no longer works.  Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome, we are to help ;) I have updated the anwser in case you want to use the unix timestamp. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I have read the documentation of [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/data.html) and I am seeing that the valueparser is used inside the x block and without the x prefix. Can you try this?

```
axes: {
  x: {
    axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisLabelFormatter,
    valueParser: function (x) { return 1000 * x; },
    valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateValueFormatter,
    ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
  }
},
```

In case it does not work, could you check if the javascript console of the browser is showing any error.

Comment: Thank you for chiming in Lucidio—the issue still occurs with your changes and xValueParser removed.  That said, thank you for directing me to the JavaScript Console.  Here is the error that’s reported:
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
dygraph.min.js (5,13421)`
I won’t have time to investigate today, but you have directed me down a path and I’ll review further and report back if I have time tomorrow.

Comment: I forced myself to make time to investigate further using dygraph.js (instead of dygraph.min.js) and, it appears, valueParser no longer exists:
`SCRIPT5022: invalid option valueParser
dygraph.js (4448,9)`
Why I get this error with dygraph.js and not dygraph.min.js I’m uncertain, but reverting my code to what it was prior to your changes leaves me with the same error I noted in my original comment so I still need to investigate further.

Comment: Then if you don´t use the option valueparser option everything works ok? If you could upload your code and the concrete libraries you are using I could try to help you

Comment: If I don’t use valueParser, the invalid option error goes away—my original code still produces the original error.  I’ll try to get my code into a JSFiddle to make it easier for you and I’ll update you when I do.  Thank you for offering to assist.

Comment: Looked into this further and it appears this is not a date formatting break.  Perhaps I should delete this question and start anew, but mouseovers still don’t function and the legend doesn’t update.  Also, the following is in the JS Console:
`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
legend.js (223,5)`
Don’t know why legend.js is listed, as I don’t directly call it.  Regardless, original code referencing 1.1.1 is at https://jsfiddle.net/oxt3ttow/4/ and the largely similar broken code referencing 2.0 is at https://jsfiddle.net/9jgtse5o/1/.  Thank you again.

Comment: Why don´t you use the dygraph-combined.js library directly? In my projects that is the library I use too.

Comment: It doesn’t appears this library is available for 2.0, or am I missing something?

Comment: So sorry. Forgot my last comment. I hope you have not lost so much time breaking your brain :( I am using the 1.1

Comment: I think I am close to solve your problem. Give 5 minutes and I post my anwser

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and right now everything is working except the "valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateValueFormatter" line. If you comment this line, all the errors dissappear except that the value is not formatted in the label. Try to take this path to find the solution